# Grafana running in Kubernetes Slack Webhook Error 502

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, grafana, slack

I set up Grafana to run in GKE (Kubernetes) with a service and default Ingress controller to open it to the internet. Everything is working without any issues.

After creating some dashboards I wanted to setup Slack alerting using the slack webhook. After filling out all the details I received a 502 bad gateway error.

I have setup a second service to open port 443(Default slack webhook port) and exposed it with `kubectl expose deployment --type=NodePort --port=443` and have also tried `--type=LoadBalancer` with no luck.

I've also tried setting up a second Ingress service pointing the second service, but then I run into readinessProbe issues.

Anyone had the same issue and if so how was it resolved?

Comment: Can you share your slack webhook configuration?

Comment: I created a webhook URL using the Slack Api and then inserted the URL in the Grafana UI under add notification channel. I've set up a loadbalancer and this says my test has completed successfully, but I don't receive the message in my channel.

Comment: For me your description is it not clear enough, are your running slack app on k8s?

Comment: I am running Grafana on k8s and want to set up slack notifications using their webhook. I have a similar setup running in a VM without any issues

Comment: If you are using slack url publicly available you don't need a load balancer to send a notification.
Check if your URL is correct and maybe check the firewall in google?

Comment: I've narrowed it down to a nameserver issue where k8s is unable to resolve external host names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Network Policy was enabled on the cluster and there were cluster policies denying outgoing traffic. After setting up my network policies for the pods in my own namespace I was able to connect without any issues.